# How to add/remove classes in specific blade templates

Tags: php, laravel

I have a navbar which is transparent on my mainpage, but I want to remove the transparent class and give it a new class with background color on a different blade template. I would use sections but it seems a bit overkill for me. Also I would like to prevent removing the layout and add it into the template itselves.

This my navbar in my app.blade.php

```html
<nav id="nav" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent">
```

But in specific blade templates I want to remove that navbar-transparent class and give it "navbar-dark bg-dark"

```html
 <nav id="nav" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
```

Is there anything I can do besides using sections or removing the whole layout template and adding it to my custom blade templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Controller method you can pass class as

```
$tempClass = "navbar-dark bg-dark";
return view("folder.view", compact("...your other arrays", "tempClass"));
```

In app.blade.php you can write,

```
@php
$tempClass = (!empty($tempClass) ? $tempClass : 'navbar-transparent')
@endphp
```

And replace

```
<nav id="nav" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent">
```

with

```
<nav id="nav" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-expand-lg {{ $tempClass }}">
```

So that you will get dynamic class name in `app.blade.php`

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I've found a better solution for my purposes. I've created a new layout file and instead of having the mainpage layout just have the exact same layout but with different classes and extend it in my blade files. Thanks for your help though!